# How to add legends horizontally in python

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I was plotting some data. When I add the legends, it is displayed vertically. How can I show it horizontally on top of plot.
The library used pyqtgraph..

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwwmF.jpg

thank you in advance

BR

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ (BTW: your screen is dusty)

Answer (score 0):

I remember there being an angle feuture where you can set it to the degrees you want  if you look in the library with all the functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Look up the docs for [`LegendItem`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/legenditem.html):

> `colCount` : Specifies the integer number of columns that the legend should be divided into. The number of rows will be calculated based on this argument. This is useful for plots with many curves displayed simultaneously. Default: 1 column.

In your code create a `LegendItem` with the number of columns that you need. Then call `legend_item.addItem` with each of your `PlotItem`s and a name.